# How to center rotating div with transform-origin?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I've been busy for so long tried to get my clock centered.
How can i center all the rotating `class=pointer` in the middle of `clock`?
It's always off the center by a  small amount whatever i try. Never perfectly centered.

Someone save me pls!

```js
const elHrs = document.getElementById('hours'),
elMin = document.getElementById('mins'),
elSec = document.getElementById('secs');


(function clock() {
    const date = new Date(),
    secs = date.getSeconds(),
    mins = date.getMinutes(),
    hrs = date.getHours();
    
    const degHrs = ((hrs / 12) * 360);
    const degSec = ((secs / 60) * 360);

    if(degSec >= 354 || degSec <= 6) {
        elSec.style.transitionDuration = "0.01s";
    } else {
        elSec.style.transitionDuration = "0.4s";
    }

    const degMin = ((mins / 60) * 360);

    if(degMin >= 354 || degMin <= 6) {
        elMin.style.transitionDuration = "0.01s";
    } else {
        elMin.style.transitionDuration = "0.4s";
    }

    elSec.style.transform = `rotate(${degSec}deg)`;
    elMin.style.transform = `rotate(${degMin}deg)`;
    elHrs.style.transform = `rotate(${degHrs}deg)`;

    return setTimeout(clock, 500);
})()
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html {
  background: black url(http://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=721&blur=50);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white; }

body {
  margin: 0; }

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh; }

section {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center; }
  section span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red; }

section h1 {
  width: 100%; }

.clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red; }

.clock:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #000; }

.pointer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  transform-origin: 100%; }

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="root">

        <section>
            <h1>A <span></span> Simple <span></span> Clock </h1>
            <div class="clock">
                <div class="pointer" id="secs"></div>
                <div class="pointer" id="mins"></div>
                <div class="pointer" id="hours"></div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <footer> footer</footer>
    </div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add position properties for `.pointer`:

```js
const elHrs = document.getElementById('hours'),
  elMin = document.getElementById('mins'),
  elSec = document.getElementById('secs');


(function clock() {
  const date = new Date(),
    secs = date.getSeconds(),
    mins = date.getMinutes(),
    hrs = date.getHours();

  const degHrs = ((hrs / 12) * 360);
  const degSec = ((secs / 60) * 360);

  if (degSec >= 354 || degSec <= 6) {
    elSec.style.transitionDuration = "0.01s";
  } else {
    elSec.style.transitionDuration = "0.4s";
  }

  const degMin = ((mins / 60) * 360);

  if (degMin >= 354 || degMin <= 6) {
    elMin.style.transitionDuration = "0.01s";
  } else {
    elMin.style.transitionDuration = "0.4s";
  }

  elSec.style.transform = `rotate(${degSec}deg)`;
  elMin.style.transform = `rotate(${degMin}deg)`;
  elHrs.style.transform = `rotate(${degHrs}deg)`;

  return setTimeout(clock, 500);
})()
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  background: black url(http://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=721&blur=50);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

section span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

section h1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.clock:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #000;
}

.pointer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  top: 47.5%;
  right: 50%;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="root">

    <section>
      <h1>A <span></span> Simple <span></span> Clock </h1>
      <div class="clock">
        <div class="pointer" id="secs"></div>
        <div class="pointer" id="mins"></div>
        <div class="pointer" id="hours"></div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer> footer</footer>
  </div>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but is there a way to do this without manually calculating percentages?

Comment: @Hyrule I can't seem to find a way without it, there's a lot going on...

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
.pointer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: white;
    transform-origin: 100%;
    top: 47%;
    left: 10%;
}
```

This should work with your original code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped clocked inside a div and then applied style of clock to clockWrapper and set margin of clock.

```
.clockWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red; }
.clock{
  margin-top: 147px;
  margin-left: 33px;
}
```

```js
const elHrs = document.getElementById('hours'),
  elMin = document.getElementById('mins'),
  elSec = document.getElementById('secs');


(function clock() {
  const date = new Date(),
    secs = date.getSeconds(),
    mins = date.getMinutes(),
    hrs = date.getHours();

  const degHrs = ((hrs / 12) * 360);
  const degSec = ((secs / 60) * 360);

  if (degSec >= 354 || degSec <= 6) {
    elSec.style.transitionDuration = "0.01s";
  } else {
    elSec.style.transitionDuration = "0.4s";
  }

  const degMin = ((mins / 60) * 360);

  if (degMin >= 354 || degMin <= 6) {
    elMin.style.transitionDuration = "0.01s";
  } else {
    elMin.style.transitionDuration = "0.4s";
  }

  elSec.style.transform = `rotate(${degSec}deg) `;
  elMin.style.transform = `rotate(${degMin}deg)`;
  elHrs.style.transform = `rotate(${degHrs}deg)`;

  return setTimeout(clock, 500);
})()
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  background: black url(http://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=721&blur=50);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

section span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

section h1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.clockWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.clock {
    margin-top: 147px;
    margin-left: 33px;
}

.clock:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #000;
}

.pointer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  transform-origin: 100%;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="root">

    <section>
      <h1>A <span></span> Simple <span></span> Clock </h1>
      <div class="clockWrapper">
        <div class="clock">
          <div class="pointer" id="secs"></div>
          <div class="pointer" id="mins"></div>
          <div class="pointer" id="hours"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer> footer</footer>
  </div>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```